# Unpivot dataframe and join pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, pivot

I have this dataframe:

```
+-------+-----+---------+
| group | id  |  value  |
+-------+-----+---------+
| A     |  92 | 123.123 |
| A     | 105 |    9034 |
| A     | 999 |     421 |
| B     |  92 |   32019 |
| B     | 105 |    3281 |
+-------+-----+---------+
```

I'd like to pivot the 'group' column so that its values become part of the 'value' column name and the observations are joined by 'id' like this:

```
+-----+---------+---------+
| id  | A_value | B_value |
+-----+---------+---------+
|  92 | 123.123 | 32019   |
| 105 |    9034 | 3281    |
| 999 |     421 | nan     |
+-----+---------+---------+
```

What's the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `set_index`, `unstack` and flatten multiindex:

```
df_out = df.set_index(['id','group']).unstack()
df_out.columns = df_out.columns.map('{0[1]}_{0[0]}'.format)
df_out = df_out.reset_index()
print(df_out)
```

Output:

```
    id      A_value      B_value
0   92      123.123      32019.0
1  105     9034.000       3281.0
2  999      421.000          NaN
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple solution using `pivot`, `add_suffix` (via @ScottBoston) and `reset_index`

```
df.pivot(index = 'id',columns = 'group',values = 'value')\
       .add_suffix('_value')\
       .reset_index()
group     id   A_value  B_value
0       92.0   123.123  32019.0
1      105.0  9034.000   3281.0
2      999.0   421.000      NaN
```

Comment: Look at using `add_suffix('_value')` before `reset_index`.

Comment: @ScottBoston updated. Thanks!

Comment: add_suffix adds a string to all the columns correct? how would you do it if there was also another values column in the original dataframe?

Comment: @jerbear You can use this: `.rename({'A':'A_value', 'B':'B_value'}, axis = 1)`